# How can I enable quick open search for files in a specific node_modules subfolder of my workspace?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

My project modules are stored in `src/node_modules` but vscode ignores them like it does to `/node_modules` so I'm unable to search with `CTRL+P`.

In the settings bellow I tried:

- Setting the `node_modules` lines to `false`
- Removing the `node_modules` lines
- Adding `**/src/node_modules/**` with `false` at the top and bottom of the lists

None of the above options worked.

```json
"search.exclude": {
  "**/node_modules": true,
  "**/bower_components": true
},

"files.watcherExclude": {
  "**/.git/objects/**": true,
  "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
  "**/node_modules/**": true
}
```

Comment: `**` is matching all sub directories, so your exclude rules are covering deep matches of `node_modules`, did you try changing it to `*/node_modules/**` or `node_modules/**` instead?

Comment: Yes I did. Still same results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to disable the `**/node_modules` pattern by setting it to `false`. I don't know why it didn't work for you. It might have been a bug that got fixed in newer versions. (I'm currently on v1.75.1)

Anyhow, with that, you can do this:

```json
"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": false,
    "node_modules": true, // and any other specific ones you still want to exclude
    "src/node_modules": false,
    ...
},
```